# VBA Excel Line throwing Error Code 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm trying to do a VBA version of an excel function which works. In Excel, here is my function.

```
=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(U2&V2,I:I&D:D,0))
```

To replicate this, I created this in VBA. Code is below, but I've tested all my variables first.

`poiUnitCost` is a range that returns L:L correctly
`poiItemNum` is a range that returns I:I correctly
`poiPONum` is a range that returns D:D correctly
`Item` returns U2 value equivalent
`PONum` returns V2 value equivalent

I'm using `Val` function because some numbers may be formatted as text or numbers, so I want it to match either way.

```vb
POPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(poiUnitCost, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(Item) & Val(PONum), poiItemNum & poiPONum, 0))
```

I'm getting error code 13 type mismatch when I run it.

Comment: You have to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` here with the formula as text. You can't do `poiItemNum & poiPONum`.

Comment: And it would be (in my opinion) easier to read and may be quicker, to load everything into arrays(based on the used range) and iterate that comparing the values till you find a match then return the correct value.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not a VBA pro or expert, and I've never used {Worksheet.Evaluate}. Can you advise how I should rewrite that line with the changes you suggest?

Comment: `POPrice = Worksheets("YourSheetName").Evaluate("=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(U2&V2,I:I&D:D,0))")`. But @ScottCraner's suggestion is probably better in the long run.

Comment: @BigBen I'm  definitely not skilled at arrays. I know a little, so I can imagine it would be a better way to do it. I'd just be eve more flumoxed. I updated what you wrote with this. POPrice = shPOI.Evaluate("=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(" & [Item] & "&" & [PONum] & ",I:I&D:D,0))"). The line doesn't throw an error now, but it does input into my POPrice range a #Name? error now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `poiItemNum & poiPONum`. You can't concatenate two multi-cell ranges.

The normal solution here is to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` with the formula as text:

```
POPrice = Worksheets("YourSheetName").Evaluate("=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(U2&V2,I:I&D:D,0))")
```

If you want to use variables instead of `U2&V2`, then add outer quotes:

```
POPrice = Worksheets("YourSheetName").Evaluate("=INDEX(L:L,MATCH(""" & Item & PONum & """,I:I&D:D,0))")
```